# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:extractDebugAnnotations'

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

I'm exercising with Firebase to build a Chat app with flutter, now I'm at the level of sending and receiving messages with Cloudfirestore.
The code doesn't have any error, and it was working before upgrading flutter to 2.5.0 after this when I try to run the project faced with this error that I couldn't fix it:

```
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:extractDebugAnnotations'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':cloud_firestore:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find kotlin-compiler-30.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.0.0/kotlin-compiler-30.0.0.jar
```

The dependencies in pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.2
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
```

Here is android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is app/build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.flash_chat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled = true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```